# Can a travel router be used as a good alternative to home WiFi?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, wireless-hotspot

As the title says, would it be a good idea to use a travel router to create a wifi network at home instead of using the WiFi modem provided by my Internet supplier, is a travel router capable of supporting multiple devices while maintaining a decent throughput?

Ideally I want to use one of my desktop computers to share a network port with a travel router so I can route all traffic through a vpn, basically turning my desktop into a wireless hotspot.

Comment: Do you have a model / brand of the travel router? It should tell you how much client it can support. If you want to simply route all traffic through VPN - why not simply buy a router that has VPN client capability? There are some router that has the ability to act as a VPN client, and connect to VPN so any traffic going through the router are routed via the VPN server that you are connected to.

Comment: I looked at TP-LINK TL-WR810N Universal Wireless 300 Mbps. I couldn't find a router cheap enough where as this travel router is very cheap.

Comment: Depends on your limitation on "multiple devices". I can't find anything from the manufacturer describing client limit, but under 10 is usually a good bet it will work. More than that - can't say for sure. But yeah if you are limited in spending money, your idea sounds feasible. The only caveat I can think of are: Your Desktop must have more than 1 Network Port (1 for internet, 1 for sharing internet), and your Desktop must be on at all time (which may be costly in terms of electricity).

Comment: Thanks for suggestions and help guys. You are right, It will cost a lot in electricity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Please take a Wireless Access Point and your desktop. Your desktop computer should have the power to route the traffic.

Or you use only your desktop computer and add a WiFi card. You should buy a wifi card with AP mode.

Comment: I'll take this as the answer due to some of the previous comments about the cost of running the desktop 24/7.  Thank you